# How to remove null in find when no file does match?

Tags: bash, scripts, find

How to remove null in stdout of find when no file does match?

```
Vformat=(mp4 wmv pgep mov)

for File in ${Vformat[@]}
do
      find $SrcDir -iname "*.$File" | xargs ls -l --time-style=full-iso
done
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I *suspect* you're asking how to prevent `xargs` from running when its standard input is empty (GNU xargs has a `-r` option for that) - but really you should probably be using find's `-exec` to avoid xargs altogether

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This site is different from forums you may have previously visited, you can take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn more. Specifically, we don't put "[Solved]" or similar in the titles here, since the questions are not just for you, but for everyone! If you post a question that gets good answers, you can mark a specific answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines of your question, I suspect what you are really asking is *"how to prevent xargs from running when its standard input is empty"* so that `ls` is never run with no argument (which would list files in the current directory).

GNU `xargs` has an option for that; from `man xargs`:

> ```
>    -r, --no-run-if-empty
>           If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
>           the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
>           no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
> ```

**However** GNU `find` also provides a mechanism to avoid piping its output to `xargs` in most cases - from `man find`:

> ```
>    -exec command {} +
>           This variant of the -exec action runs the specified  command  on
>           the  selected  files, but the command line is built by appending
>           each selected file name at the end; the total number of  invoca‐
>           tions  of  the  command  will  be  much  less than the number of
>           matched files.  The command line is built in much the  same  way
>           that  xargs builds its command lines.
> ```

So for example you could do

```
Vformat=(mp4 wmv pgep mov)

for File in "${Vformat[@]}"
do
      find "$SrcDir" -iname "*.$File" -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} +
done
```

If you want to avoid the overhead of calling `find` multiple times, then one way to do that would be to convert your array of extensions into an array of `-iname xxx` arguments connected with the `-o` logical OR conjunction:

```
Vformat=(mp4 wmv pgep mov)

args=()
for File in "${Vformat[@]}"
do
  args+=( -o -iname "*.$File" )
done
```

and then

```
find "$SrcDir" -type f \( "${args[@]:1}" \) -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} +
```

The array slice `${args[@]:1}` removes a leading `-o` and the literal brackets `\(` and `\)` group the OR list since `-exec` has AND precedence.

Finally, if you just need file names and mtimes then you might consider using the `find` command's `-printf` instead of the external `ls`:

```
find "$SrcDir" -type f \( "${args[@]:1}" \) -printf '%TF %TT %Tz\t%p\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase your find-fu. Reread `man find`, and do something like the following **** UNTESTED **** :

```
Vformat=(mp4 wmv pgep mov)



find "$SrcDir" -type f \
 \( -iname '*.mp4' -o \
   \( -iname '*.wmv' -o \
     \( -iname '*.pgep' -o \
       \( -iname '*.mov' \
       \) \
     \) \
   \) \
  \) \
  -print0 | \
xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty \
    ls -l --time-style=full-iso
```

Here's a quick rundown:

- The backslash inverts the "specialness" of the next character
  "`\`Newline" is treated as a space, `\(` and `\)` ARE "special" to `find`, and are used to group expressions.
- `"$SrcDir"` Always quote variables
- `-type f`  We only care about *files*.
- `'*.mp4'`  Use single quotes to delay expansion by the shell
- By combining all the `-iname` tests with `-o` (`find`'s "OR"), you only make one pass through "$SrcDir", rather than FOUR.
- `-print0` each filename is separated by ASCII `NUL` (a character that, along with `/`, is forbidden in file names). This lets you handle Filenames with spaces and other funny characters.
- `xargs -0` accept the `NUL` separated list of filenames.
- `--no-run-if-empty`  don't execute if the generated argument list contains no filenames (in case `find` outputs junk at the end).

Generating the `find` command from `Vformat` is left undone. Hint: Use 2 variables, one to accumulate the "`\( -iname '*.foo' -o` " part, and the other to accumulate the ") "s.